# Changing transform css style causes Recalculate Style / Update Layer Tree

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, css-animations

In [this example](https://jsbin.com/wupejop/5/edit?html,output), I'm doing my (on-scroll) transformations with hopes of only touching the compositor, however, inspecting it in Chrome, Recalculate Style and Update Layer Tree are being reported in purple (meaning expensive operation).

[image]

How do I prevent any other work other than the compositor / gpu transformations in this example?

```js
 const scroller = document.querySelector('scroller');
 const width = scroller.offsetWidth;
 const scrollWidth = scroller.scrollWidth;
 const elements = document.querySelectorAll('scrolled-item');
 scroller.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scroll = scroller.scrollLeft;
  const ratio = (scroll + width) / scrollWidth;
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
   elements.forEach(el => {
    el.firstChild.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ratio * 360}deg) rotateX(${ratio * 360}deg) scaleX(${1 - ratio})`;
   })
  })
 });
```

```css
 scroller {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  background: silver
 }
 scrolled-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

 }
 scrolled-item gymnastics {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: gray;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 scrolled-item div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
<scroller>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
 <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
</scroller>
```

Comment: maybe by using css variables instead?

Comment: @MisterJojo it's not an option for my use case. I'm applying different transformations to each element in the viewport.

Comment: that's not a problem css variables also work in media Queries

Comment: @MisterJojo to clarify, it's different transformation based on the element's position relative to the viewport. Media queries can't help me with that.

Comment: Did you solve @daniel? We have exact same issue (transform invalidation causing reflow due to style recalculation on scroll)

Comment: @user3919920 nope, still no revelation : /

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing with the viewport, and I don't think it can be a handicap for using the css variables.

In the meantime here is what I had in mind, I have not answered the questions on performance, but I think this answer is faster at runtime than your previous code

```js
const scroller    = document.querySelector('scroller')
  ,   element0    = scroller.querySelector('scrolled-item')
  ,   off_width   = scroller.offsetWidth
  ,   scrollWidth = scroller.scrollWidth
  ;
for (let i=0;i<58;i++)
  {
  scroller.appendChild (element0.cloneNode(true))
  }
scroller.onscroll=()=>
  {
  let scroll = scroller.scrollLeft 
    , ratio  = (scroll + off_width) / scrollWidth
    , ratioDeg = Math.fround(ratio * 360) 
    ;
  scroller.style.setProperty('--turnXZ', ratioDeg + 'deg')
  scroller.style.setProperty('--scalX', (1 - ratio))
  }
```

```css
scroller {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  background: silver;
  --turnXZ : 0deg;
  --scalX  : 1;
}
scrolled-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
scrolled-item gymnastics {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(50, 47, 209, 0.658);
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scaleX(var(--scalX)) rotateX(var(--turnXZ) ) rotateZ(var(--turnXZ) );
}
scrolled-item div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<scroller>
  <scrolled-item><gymnastics></gymnastics><div>do</div></scrolled-item>
</scroller>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. It might've even [made things slower](https://imgur.com/LudFcUL).